# How to add author on WordPress Pages? Not blog article page

Tags: author

I am having trouble adding author on each pages of a website built in WordPress.
Any idea how can I do that automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a function which does this for you. You'll need some experiences with HTML, CSS, PHP to style the output and understand what that function does:

- [`the_author()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author) which displays the author of the post/page.

In your theme will most likely be a `page.php` template where you can add these on pages into [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) like so:

```
<?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="author"><?php the_author(); ?></div>        
    <?php endwhile; ?>      
<?php endif; ?>
```

Keep in mind you should create a child theme to do a change like that in order to avoid losing any data if the theme updates.

Comment: Thanks Castiblanco, I've already tried with the_author(), unfortunately it placed the author above the breadcrumbs. We still need to do some CSS changes in order to have it solved.

Comment: Well, that's not the question here, you can edit your question adding the complete code and what you want to achieve